# A basic question about the spectral theorem for self adjoint compact operator..

Tags: functional-analysis, self-adjoint-operators

In the statement of this theorem which i state from the book of conway that if T is a compact self adjoint operator on a hilbert space then T have countable no of non zero eigen value ln and there exist orthogonal projection Pn onto Ker(T-lnI) such that PnPm=0 if n≠m and T=summation (lnPn).(convergent in operator norm).
now i am stuck how to show RanT=orthogonal direct sum of ImPn i.e closure(<{ImPn:n€N}>) ..where  means a subspace spanned by X..
I am able to show only one direction that is ImT is a subspace of the orthogonal direct sum of ImPn..but the other inclision i could not..any help will b appreciated..

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If $v\in {\rm Im}P_n$ then $Tv=\lambda_nv.$ As $\lambda_n\neq 0$ we get $v\in {\rm Im} T.$